# Create ML - Is it possible to find the position of detected object?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, createml

I'm trying to build an object detection model with Create ML. In addition to detecting the type of objects in a picture, I would like it to give me in the output the coordinates (or the position) of each detected object.

How can I get the coordinates of each detected object in the output picture?

Is it possible to do that with Create ML? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the object detector returns an array of `VNRecognizedObjectObservation` objects of what it finds. Each object contains an array of matching labels, a confidence value and a bounding box as well as other information.

The bounding box is normalized, so you need to convert it into pixel coordinates with `VNImageRectForNormalizedRect` before you use it.

Apple has an excellent sample app with detailed explanations which you can [find here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture).